# How to enforce interface generics' rules on inherited type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, .net-core

I have an interface that defines a contract and that enforces the `TEntity` to be a class and to have the IBaseEntity interface implemented:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey>
    where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity<TEntityKey>, new() { /* Some code. */ }
```

I have an abstract class that implements this interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey>
    : IBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey> { /* Some code. */ }
```

The base class is giving me a compilation error:

> The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'IBaseRepository'

This can be solved by adding the `where` keyword like I have in the interface, but I was wondering why the class doesn't inherit that rule from the interface and if there's any way to do that.

Comment: There's nothing to inherit. The rule says that *IBaseRepository*'s type arguments should have certain criteria. It says nothing about *AbstractBaseRepository*'s

Comment: An educated guess would say that it's because you are implementing an interface. You see, a class might implement more than one interface, some of them might have conflicting generic constraints - Had these constraints been "inherited" to the classes implementing these interfaces, you would be in a much bigger problem (because you might not even know what the constraints are) Also, there is nothing forcing you to use a generic class when implementing a generic interface...